# I am unable to import a file no matter what I do

Tags: python, python-import

And although this was asked a MILLION times, this case is special, because either I am very dumb, or my laptop is.
So to make sure that everybody is on the same page, here is what I want to do: use `import menu` inside of `fish life imulator.py`, and here is the file tree that I did:

- `fish_life_simulator`

  - `fish_life_simulator.py`
  - `extra_programs`

    - `__init__.py`
    - `menu.py`

And I tried EVERYTHING that I found, `os.chdir` redirect to the extra programs folder, `sys.path.append` or `sys.path.insert`, `import file` or `from file import def`, `__init__.py` as you can see, but I always seem to get the same error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'menu'

Edit: here is a sample of my code:
`fish_life_simulator`

```
import pygame, random, time, sys, os
from pygame.locals import *

os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))

pygame.init()

size_of_monitor = pygame.display.Info()

flags = RESIZABLE

width = size_of_monitor.current_w - 25
height = size_of_monitor.current_h - 50

from extra_programs import menu

screen, screen_size, menu_background_image, menu_background_stretched_image, menu_background_rect = initiation(width, height, flags)
```

`menu.py`

```
def initiation(width, height, flags):
    
    
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), flags)

    screen_size = screen.get_size()

    menu_background_image = pygame.image.load(r'sprites\menu_background.jpg')
    menu_background_stretched_image = pygame.transform.scale(menu_background_image, (screen_size))
    menu_background_rect = menu_background_stretched_image.get_rect()

    return screen, screen_size, menu_background_image, menu_background_stretched_image, menu_background_rectscreen, screen_size, menu_background_image, menu_background_stretched_image, menu_background_rect
```

Comment: First off, I strongly recommend not putting spaces in file or directory names.

Comment: Second, have you tried `from extra_programs import menu` or `from .extra_programs import menu`?

Comment: ok, I edited the question to the same way that I edited my files

Comment: `from .extra_programs import menu`. Because menu is inside extra_programs dir which has an init file which turns it into a package.

Comment: When having these successive tries with no success you're better off stopping what you're doing and studying the docs.

Comment: @Niloct @MattDMo ```from .extra_programs import menu``` gave me ```ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package``` and when I used ```from extra_programs import menu```, it didn't actually import the functions for some reason

Comment: how and _where_ are you calling this code from. from the root of the folder I have no issues importing anything

Comment: What do you mean "I used `from extra_programs import menu`, it didn't actually import the functions for some reason"?  Can you show us the actual code that is failing, along with the full error traceback?  (You're referring to the functions as `menu.funcname()`, not just `funcname()`, right?)

Comment: I can not reproduce this error, using this same structure I can call the code just fine

Comment: I am now gonna edit the question with the bare minimum of my program to replicate the problem oh yeah and this is the error that I get: NameError: name 'initiation' is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work with the following folder structure and the following code:

```
fish_life_simulator
|-- extra_programs
|   |-- __init__.py
|   `-- menu.py
`-- fish_life_simulator.py
```

menu.py

```
def menu():
    print("hello from menu")
```

fish_life_simulator.py

```
from extra_programs import menu

menu.menu()
```

There is no need at all to edit the path or something like that.

Just navigate into the folder `fish_life_simulator` and run the code with `python fish_life_simulator.py`.

If you don't want to type the `menu.` prefix, you can adapt `fish_life_simulator.py` like below:

```
from extra_programs.menu import menu

menu()
```

In your code, you are lacking the prefix, when calling `initiation(...)`, it should be `menu.initiation(...)`. You need to decide for one of the above ways to import.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question though, this just shows you can't reproduce the error

Comment: You may be right, thanks for the hint. Now, it does. I added the reason for his error in the last section.

Comment: Oh now it makes sense! And that even gets rid of all of the annoying warnings! And also thanks for sharing the files.exclude article, that was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

Inside a folder `fish_life_simulator` execute

```sh
PYTHONPATH=. python fish_life_simulator.py
```

Where in `fish_life_simulator.py` your import are

```py
from extra_programs import menu
...
```

Or one level outside folder `fish_life_simulator` execute

```sh
PYTHONPATH=fish_life_simulator/  python fish_life_simulator/fish_life_simulator.py
```

Where in `fish_life_simulator.py` your import are

```py
from fish_life_simulator.extra_programs import menu
...
```

Comment: is that using cmd? because that might be a problem, as does that mean that if I transfer the entire folder ```fish_life_simulator``` to another computer it won't work anymore?

Comment: Yes. Basically, we are trying to tell Python which places it should lock for packages. You can debug your code by running `import sys;print(sys.path)` before the imports to see where the script will look for packages to import

Comment: there's no need to modify `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: No, you don't need to copy the contents of folders that have nothing to do with the code

Comment: wait but... are you sure that there is no way to do this other than through cmd? Because I do plan to send this project to my dad, as I really hyped him up with it, as this is the first "big" python project that I am making, but I won't be able to run that command on HIS computer.